# consumer not acknowledging message

Tags: python-2.7, rabbitmq, message-queue, amqp, pika

I have a channel.basic_ack however when I check in the rabbitmq admin ui, it stays unacked rather than acked.  Here is my code to ack the message

```
def handle_payload(self, channel, method, properties, body):
        #self.taskhub.server.invoke('SendTaskNotification', body['userId'], body['taskId'])
        discovery = body
        channel.basic_ack(method.delivery_tag)
        print "acked " + str(method.delivery_tag)
        self.medium.server.invoke('DetectDevice', discovery)
```

To my understand it should ack the message as soon as channel.basic_ack is called.  However this is not happening.

Answer (score 1):

Pika documentation http://pika.readthedocs.io/en/0.10.0/modules/adapters/blocking.html says, delivery_tag is a default parameter.
change the above code with the below line:

```
channel.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method.delivery_tag)
```

Comment: Send me the channel.basic_consume statement let me check on it.